# Cardinality of an uncountable set

Tags: real-analysis

If I have shown that the cardinality of a set is at most $C(1+2+3...)$, where C is a constant, does that mean it is countable?

Comment: What doe $C(1+2+3+......)$ mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes C(1+2+3+...) can be replaced by 1+1+1+... so it is countable.

Details: C1=1+1+1..., C times.  2C=1+1+1... 2C times, etc.

Note:  this proof is very similar to the proof that algebraic numbers (roots of polynomials with integer coefficients) are countable.